# i'm getting a null user id when i create a new artisan in a laravel and vue project

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Here is my controller that holds the store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

       $artisan = Artisan::create($request->all() + ['user_id' => Auth::user()]);
       return $artisan;
    }
```

Can figure out why Auth::user() is pushing a null value to the db instead of picking the current authenticated user id.

please help guys.

Answer (score 0):

`Auth::user()` returns a instance of the `User` class (if the user is logged in).

You have to pick the `id` from it, like this:

```
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;
```

Comment: Thank @Phiter but when i do $user_id = Auth::user() ->id; i get this error message -> message: "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: Means you didn't configure auth properly or there is no logged user,

Answer (score 0):

To get user data from Auth::user(), you have to follow this.

- You have to use Auth class for login.

  ```
  if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {}
  ```
- You have to include all the routes under **web** middleware where you want to access authenticated user data.

  ```
  Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::post('/dashboard', 'Controller@dashboard');
  }
  ```

> As the value comes from Session and web middleware has Session
>   activated.